# Is there a way to stop uploading an attachment in outlook web add-in?

Tags: javascript, xml, outlook-web-addins

I'm trying to get an attachment from an outlook mailbox, but I don't want it to be uploaded to microsoft server for security purposes.

I added the extension point in my xml file:

`<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="LaunchEvent">`
  `<LaunchEvents>`
    `<LaunchEvent Type="OnMessageAttachmentsChanged" FunctionName="test" />`
  `</LaunchEvents>`
 `<SourceLocation resid="residUILessFunctionFileUrl" />`
`</ExtensionPoint>`
But my test function is only called once the file as been uploaded to the server. I was wondering if I could do and event.preventDefault() before the file is uploaded, but the event returned by the launchevent isn't a normal html event.

Here's my test function:

`function test(event){`     
     `event.preventDefault() //This isn't possible`
    `console.log(event)`
`}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the feature you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [Tech Community Page](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform). Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process.